# How to sort a HashMap with DateTime object

Tags: java, android

I want to sort a HashMap of timestamps .

Here is my timestamps hashmap.

```
Map<String, DateTime> timestamps = new HashMap<> ();
```

I dont know which method i should use to sort this type of hashmaps . So I cant provide any additional code.

Thank you for ur help !